# mysql client preparedQuery no close

Tags: vert.x

```
public static void updateToDb(MySQLPool jdbcClient, String sql, JsonArray params, Handler<AsyncResult<Object>> handler) {
        jdbcClient
                .preparedQuery(sql)
                .execute(Tuple.tuple(params.getList()), ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        RowSet<Row> rows = ar.result();
                        handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(rows.rowCount()));
                    } else {
                        handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar.cause().getMessage()));
                    }
                });
    }
```

When this method executes multiple times, Prompt this error: Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count

vertx version:3.9.8

Comment: When an SQL statement is executed with an error, the number of Prepared_stmt_count is increased
For example, the insert Duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Vert.x, in fact.

`max_prepared_stmt_count` is a configuration of your MySQL database.

This is quite strange, though, since the default is 16K, which is quite high.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: When an SQL statement is executed with an error, the number of Prepared_stmt_count is increased. For example, the insert Duplicate.